# function with switch case doesn't give an output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that gets date and supposed to return the sign according to the date. for example if one's input is 15.4.1996

the output will be Aries

I check only day and month (year doesn't meter) but the problem that currantly I don't get any output. why?

```js
function yourSign() {
    var signDate = $("input[name='birthDate']").val();
    switch (signDate) {

        case 0:
            outputSign = "Aries"

            var dateFrom = "21/03";
            var dateTo = "20/04";

            var dateFrom = dateFrom.split("/");
            var dateTo = dateTo.split("/");

            var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1]) - 1); // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
            var to = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1]) - 1);
            signDate = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1]) - 1);

            var signOutput = console.log(signDate > from && signDate < to)
            $("#output").val(signOutput);

            //  document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value = signOutput;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>your sign</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
   <form id="yourSign">
      <label for=birthDate>birthdate</label><br /><input type="date" name="birthDate" id="birthDate" /><br />
      <button onclick="yourSign()" id="sendSign" name="sendSign">send</button><br>
      <label for="output" id="output">your sign is: </label><br><input type="text" name="output">
   </form>
```

Comment: `signDate > from && SignDate < to` typo, case sensitivity - your IDE should see this for you if you set it up correctly

Comment: The returned value will be a string, but you're comparing to a number. Try using `"0"`.

Comment: its `birthDate` not `Birthdate`

Comment: try opening the console and check for errors. pretty sure the typo mentioned above should pop up in the console.

Comment: Ive started with Aries and needs to do it for the rest signs @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @ladyd Where do ```d1```, ```d2``` and ```c``` come from? Or are they typos, too?

Comment: This code is all over the place. Check all variable names for spelling (cAsE-sensitive!) and be sure to initialize each one but only once!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues in your code that need to be fixed :

Line 3 :

```
switch (signDate) {
        case 0:
```

=> Why would you switch case over the string representation of a date? When is it supposed to be evaluted to 0 ?

Lines 8-12 :

```
    var dateFrom = "21/03";
    var dateTo = "20/04";

    var dateFrom = dateFrom.split("/");
    var dateTo = dateTo.split("/");
```

=> You are declaring `dateFrom` and `dateTo` as string and then re-declaring them as arrays (the result of the `split()` function). You should avoid doing that, it's kind of confusing. And I'm assuming, from the lines after, that you meant to name you arrays `d1` and `d2`.

Lines 14-16 :

```
   var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1]) - 1); // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
   var to = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1]) - 1);
   signDate = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1]) - 1);
```

=> `c`, `d1` and `d2` are undefined. I guess `d1` and `d2` are the result of the date string being splitted (see above). But what about `c`?

Line 18 :

```
var signOutput = console.log(signDate > from && signDate < to)
```

=> You are setting the returned value of `console.log()` to the signOutput variable. `console.log` prints stuff to the console and returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"function with switch case doesn't give an output"*

This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). OP should approach this problem knowing certain facts:

- User input has two ranges: **month:** 1 to 12 Numbers and **days:** 1 to 31 Numbers. Date API and/or `<input type="date">` is complex and year isn't needed. ***Only 2 Numbers from the user is required***.
- A `<form>` and its form controls (ie `<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>`, etc.) can be used to constrain user input so functions can be written to expect specific input and always be expected to output the same results. working with the data from `<input type="date">` one must consider whether it's instantiated to an Object or not, formatting, etc.  Try a ***`<select>` for months and `<input type="number">` for days*** instead.
- jQuery is loaded so there are certain things to consider. Never use an on-event attribute. jQuery event handling is versatile and powerful so take advantage of it.

  > `<button onclick="fnc();" type="button">Done</button>`
  >
  > `<button type="button">Done</button> ...`
  > `... $('button').on('click', fnc);`
- JavaScript is loosely typed so always be aware of what the arguments are from one line to the next. Try to focus on a single type throughout a function. There's only 2 Numbers that user has provided so once converted from String to real Numbers, keep them that way until the results are displayed to user.

---

A `switch()` is useful if one must handle multiple possibilities in a similar and limited fashion. Use `if`/`if...else`/`else` statements if resolving a condition leads to further conditions. Here's an outline of the `switch()` provided in the demo:

- One Number is passed: 0 to 11 -- the index number from the `<select>` representing the `case MONTH:`.
- One Number is referenced: 1 to 31 -- the number from the `<input type="number">` representing the `DAY`.

  ```
   case MONTH:
     SIGN = DAY < Specific_day ? "sign A" : "signB";
     break;
  ```
- A Ternary: 
  ***if*** `DAY` Number ***is less than*** **[<]** `Specific_day` Number  **then** **[?]**...
  `SIGN` String **equals** **[=]** `"sign A"` String ...
  ***else*** **[:]**
  `SIGN` String **equals** **[=]** `"sign B"` String

The function `maxDays()` regulates the input by ensuring that the value of `input#day` maximum is correct according to the month and that it never exceeds below the minimum of 1 and the maximum of 30, 29, or 31.

---

```js
$('#month, #day').on('input', maxDays);
$('button').on('click', zSign);

function maxDays() {
  var num = Number($(this).val());
  var max;

  if ($(this).is('#month')) {
    if (num % 2 === 0) {
      max = 30;
    } else if (num === 1) {
      max = 29;
    } else {
      max = 31;
    }
    return $('#day').attr('max', max).val('1');
  }

  if ($(this).is('#day')) {
    if (num < 1) {
      num = 1;
    } else if (num > max) {
      num = max;
    } else {
      num = num;
    }
    return $('#day').val(num);
  }
  return false;
}

function zSign() {
  var month = Number($('#month').val());
  var day = Number($('#day').val());
  var sign;

  switch (month) {
    case 0:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Capricorn" : "Aquarius";
      break;
    case 1:
      sign = day < 19 ? "Aquarius" : "Pisces";
      break;
    case 2:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Pisces" : "Aries";
      break;
    case 3:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Aries" : "Taurus";
      break;
    case 4:
      sign = day < 21 ? "Taurus" : "Gemini";
      break;
    case 5:
      sign = day < 22 ? "Gemini" : "Cancer";
      break;
    case 6:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Cancer" : "Leo";
      break;
    case 7:
      sign = day < 24 ? "Leo" : "Virgo";
      break;
    case 8:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Virgo" : "Libra";
      break;
    case 9:
      sign = day < 24 ? "Libra" : "Scorpio";
      break;
    case 10:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Scorpio" : "Sagittarius";
      break;
    case 11:
      sign = day < 23 ? "Sagittarius" : "Capricorn";
      break;
    default:
      sign = null;
      break;
  }
  return $('#output').val(sign);
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 500 16px/1.3 Verdana
}

select,
input,
output,
button,
label {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 5px 1px;
}

#day {
  width: 4ch;
  text-align: center;
}

#output::before {
  content: "\a0";
}
```

```html
<form id="zodiac">
  <label for="month">Month:</label>
  <select id="month">
    <option value='0' selected>January</option>
    <option value='1'>February</option>
    <option value='2'>March</option>
    <option value='3'>April</option>
    <option value='4'>May</option>
    <option value='5'>June</option>
    <option value='6'>July</option>
    <option value='7'>August</option>
    <option value='8'>September</option>
    <option value='9'>October</option>
    <option value='10'>November</option>
    <option value='11'>December</option>
  </select>
  <label for="day"> Day: </label>
  <input id="day" type='number' min='1' max='30' value='1'>
  <button type='button'>Done</button><br>
  <label for="output">Your sign is </label><output id='output'></output>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```